# What would the best way to be to create a view in mysql with the following database layouts?

Tags: php, mysql, view, mariadb

I have looked through a TON of the mysql view examples so I am guessing what I am trying to do may not be possible.

I have multiple databases : db1, db2, db3 .......
Each have a table: quotes
Columns in identical tables: DateSubmitted DATETIME, TimeFinished DATETIME, Status VARCHAR(64)

I am trying to get a view that I would create or re-create as new databases are added that can do some calculations between the DateSubmitted and TimeFinished based on Status (Error, TimeOut, Success)

The result I am looking for would be something like this:

```
Database|AvgTimeLast24Hours|AvgTimeLastWeek|AvgTimeLastMonth

|db1|60|48 | 40 |

| db2  | 185 | 125 | 105

|db3 | 14 | 18 | 23 |
```

The average columns would be in minutes, I have the queries to get the calculations but when I try to put it into a view I know I am doing it wrong.

Does anyone have any examples?

Comment: "I have multiple databases : db1, db2, db3 ....... Each have a table: quotes Columns in identical tables: DateSubmitted DATETIME, TimeFinished DATETIME, Status VARCHAR(64)" Wierd design what causes you problems now.. What you can do is use information_schema.TABLES and generate dynamic (which uses union all) SQL and execute it with PREPARE and EXECUTE i think that's a better option then making a view.

Comment: Thank you @RaymondNijland, I am doing something similar now. I was hoping to create the view so that the performance was better than all of the individual queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a query to generate the result set you want, presumably from one of your multiple databases.  Let's say it's `SELECT SUM(foo) foo, baz FROM quotes ORDER BY baz` . (I know it isn't, but you didn't show your query.)

Then, in that same database you can create this as a view, easily.

```
CREATE VIEW summary
    AS
 SELECT SUM(foo) foo, baz FROM quotes ORDER BY baz;
```

Get that view working properly.

Then you can create another view taking the union of the tables in your various databases.

```
 CREATE VIEW all_quotes AS
             SELECT * FROM db1.quotes
  UNION ALL  SELECT * FROM db2.quotes
  UNION ALL  SELECT * FROM db3.quotes
   /* etc etc ad nauseam */
```

Then change your first view to reference `all_quotes` instead of `quotes`.  Of course, this only works if all the databases are on the same server (or if you do something with remote table references, which you can look up).

You can't use variables in queries for database or table names. Those must be constant text. Raymond is correct when he says you won't be able to write a query that successfuly refers to the union of all the databases in your system. You'll have to bootstrap that operation.

1. write a query (using `information_schema.TABLES`, probably) to write your `CREATE VIEW AS...` query, or some other query referencing all your databases.
2. run that query you made.

You can create and run it either in a php program, or using [MySQL's server-side flavor of prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) (a different flavor from the prepared statements in `mysqli` or `PDO`).

The trick is to get things working stage by stage.

**Pro tip:**  A separate database for each customer is notoriously hard to scale up. The more successful you become, the harder it gets. That's not good.

Comment: This is the suggestion I was looking for. I am going to do it tonight and will reply back.